# In PHP, how to keep a random number var from changing each time input is changed?

Tags: php

I am attempting to make a random number guessing game in PHP.  The guesses are entered into the $_GET var in the address bar after a ?.  However, each time the enter key is pressed the random number itself changes. How can I keep this random number intact until the game is lost or won.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess Gaming</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Guess the correct Number</h1>
    <p>
    <?php
      $randomNum = rand(0, 150);
      if(empty($_GET["guess"])){
          echo "Missing guess parameter.";

      } elseif(!empty($_GET["guess"])){

    if(is_numeric($_GET["guess"])){
        if($_GET["guess"] === $randomNum){
            echo "Congratulations-- You are right";
        } elseif($_GET["guess"] < $randomNum){
            echo "Your guess is too low.";
        } elseif($_GET["guess"] > $randomNum){
            echo "Your guess is too high.";
        }

    } else {
        echo $_GET["guess"]." isn't numeric.";
    }
}   
?>
</p>
<p>  
<?php
   echo $randomNum;
?>
</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this game include money? in other words does it have to be secure from fraud?

Comment: @MehdiBounya Would you bet money on this? :-)

Comment: For how long should this random number be keept? Should user 2 have the same number to guess on or should it get a new number?

Comment: No money.  Just learning PHP.

Comment: @Andreas No way, I asked that so I can see if storing the number in a session is a valid answer, as Andrea mentioned, is the number unique for different users?

Comment: Use a `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Save `$randomNum` into session, then just use that session when checking. When he will be right, reset that session with new number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sessions. Put `session_start();` at the top of your PHP script.

Generate a new random number whenever the current one is guessed, or if there is none yet:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['secret_random_number']))
{
  $_SESSION['secret_random_number'] = mt_rand(0,150);
}
```

Get the previously stored number like this:

```
$randomNumber = $_SESSION['secret_random_number'];
```

Comment: Better answer. Just add: `if($_GET["guess"] === $randomNum){ unset($_SESSION['secret_random_number']);}` also.

Comment: No that's not a better answer because more has to be done when the guess is correct.

Comment: Sad. This is not the best answer. This is feeding a man a fish for a day. Stop being afraid of the official documentation.

Comment: @jhilgeman It is a better answer. Yours is not an answer. It's a link. Thats it. It should be posted as a comment, not an answer, I can't understand why you even got upvoted at all. This answer however is a good attempt to help the asker.

Comment: This answer isn't helping the asker in the long run. He said he's learning PHP and you're trying to give him a quick answer instead of pointing him to a resource that not only has the same code answer but has additional information to help the asker with future questions.

Comment: Not to mention that this answer doesn't explain how session variables work or what they are. This is just code being thrown at someone who IS TRYING TO LEARN PHP.

Comment: @jhilgeman Often, learning is done better through simple, self-explanatory examples than tedious manuals. I deliberately left out the code for the "whenever the current one is guessed" situation. Once the asker understands the concepts herein, he will have an easy time finishing it himself.

Answer (score 1):

Store the correct answer in a session variable. Session variable persist from page to page and aren't visible to the end user. 
http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

EDIT:
Adding the code example from the documentation, since some people are otherwise voting in retaliation to delete a completely valid answer simply because it doesn't have code.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

That is the code principle. Just change out the variable names and use your existing logic for generating the random number.